# No such directory or file - Mac

Tags: unix, directory, rclone

I'm pretty rookie to this, but I managed to get this code running when I had a PC.
Now I want to get this working on my MacBook.

I'm using Rclone to sync to Jottacloud, and I want to make a clickable file, just as a .bat file in windows.

This is my simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /
cd /Applications/rclone
rclone  copy /Users/windsvendsen/Pictures/Billedebank Jottacloud:Billedebank
```

Running it in Terminal, without the #!/bin/bash, it works as it should.

But when I save it as a file, without extension, and running `chmod 744` on it, it returns with the error "No such file directory"

And here does my knowledge end.

It is probably a pretty simple problem, but I do not manage to get the essence out of my google searches.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide all bash commands that you were trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do ls on the directory and see if the file actually got created

Comment: Yes, the file exists.